# Serialization Issue in Java

Tags: java, serialization, hashmap

I have a data type that contains long timestamps, a hashmap , Set and another double array. I serialized this data type and didn't get any exception while running however, When I read that file, map and double array comes out to be null? Basically I can print out the numbers to the console before writing but double arrays and map are null. Sorry if I explained this badly. I have been working on this for a while now...

What seems to be the problem? What are the NotSerializable classes? Is there any way of making it serializable?

Thanx for taking your time.

Comment: Can you post the code for your class?

Comment: Did you mark the class as Serializable?  Post the code if you can.

Comment: is your double array declared final?

Comment: @Ron, what does final matter?

Comment: I'm thinking the problem exists between the keyboard and the seat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both HashMaps and arrays of primitives ( doubles ) are serializable. Its possible that your HashMap has objects that are not marked Serializable? Hard to tell without looking at the code.

Here is a quick sample ---

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Ser {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // Serialize an int[]
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("test.ser"));
        out.writeObject(new double[] {3.1, 1.1});
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("test1.ser"));
        HashMap<String, String> aa = new HashMap<String, String>();
        aa.put("bla" , "bla1");
        out.writeObject(aa);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        // Deserialize the int[]
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("test.ser"));
        double[] array = (double[]) in.readObject();
        in.close();

        // Print out contents of deserialized int[]
        System.out.println("It is " + (array instanceof Serializable) + " that we can serialize double[]");
        for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(", " + array[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();

        in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("test1.ser"));
        HashMap<String, String> bb = (HashMap<String, String>) in.readObject();
        in.close();

        // Print out contents of deserialized int[]
        System.out.println("It is " + (bb instanceof Serializable) + " that we can serialize HashMap");
        System.out.print(bb);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you would need to make your class serializable by implementing the serializable interface in the java.io package; and it would look something like this

```
    import java.io.Serializable;

    public class YourClassNameHere implements Serializable
    {
          //your class code and methods would go here
    }
```

this should fix your problem pretty easily.

Comment: He has already serialized the class with no exceptions, so he must have already done this.

Answer (score 1):

This answer may be far too basic, but check whether your fields are not **transient** nor **static**.

Answer (score -1):

I have run into `Collection`s resolving to `null` before, when the serialized `Collection` is empty. Trick is to define a `Object readResolve()` method on your class, which is called by the serialization infrastructure after the object is read from the data source. From here you can return a new instance of your class with the nulls replaced with a real empty `Collection`. So something like:

```
public class MyClass implements Serializable {
    private final Map<String,String> foo;
    public MyClass() {
        foo = new HashMap<String,String>();
    }
    public MyClass(final Map<String,String> foo) {
        this.foo = new HashMap<String,String>(foo);
    }
    ...
    public Object readResolve() {
        return (foo == null ? new MyClass() : new MyClass(foo));
    }
}
```

Copying over the other fields you have defined as needed.

Comment: 'I have run into Collections resolving to null before, when the serialized Collection is empty.' I find that impossible to believe, sorry. Several other things would have to be wrong for that to happen.

Comment: Impossible, you say? I can assure you, it did happen. And does happen. NB: javabin is not the only way to serialize data. Other formats may choose to represent an empty collection as no output.

Comment: The OP is asking about NotSerializable classes. Ergo he is using Java Object Serialization. Ergo (a) the situation you describe cannot occur in the OP's context and (b) this is all irrelevant.